# Select Image with Javascript and save ID

Tags: javascript

I have a div container with several images. I want the user to select an image (avatar) from the provided list. Then the avatar image will be uploaded and also accessible. Once the user selects the avatar, I want to save the location of the selected avatar to my database. What is the best way to select the image? Is there any easy way to do this?

HTML

```
<div class="image-container">
      <img src="images/gorillaAvatars/brownGorilla.png" id="brownGorilla">
      <img src="images/gorillaAvatars/gorilla.png" id="Gorilla">
      <img src="images/gorillaAvatars/greenGorilla.png" id="greenGorilla">
      <img src="images/gorillaAvatars/kidGorilla.png" id="kidGorilla">
      <img src="images/gorillaAvatars/surpriseGorilla.png" id="surpriseGorilla">

 </div>
```

CSS

```
<style>

 .image-container{
        width:60%;
        border: solid magenta 1px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 30px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
      }
    
      img{
        width:80px;
      }
      img:hover,
      img:focus,
      img:active{
        background-color: blue;
        border-radius: 20px;
      }
<style>
```

Javascript

```
const brownGorillaAvatar = "https://brownGorilla.png";
const mainGorillaAvatar ="https://gorilla.png"
const greenGorillaAvatar ="https://greenGorilla.png"
const kidGorillaAvatar ="https://kidGorilla.png"
const surpriseGorillaAvatar ="https://surpriseGorilla.png"

const avatar = [brownGorillaAvatar,mainGorillaAvatar,greenGorillaAvatar,kidGorillaAvatar, surpriseGorillaAvatar]

brownG.addEventListener('click', avatarSelect);
bigG.addEventListener('click', avatarSelect1);
greenG.addEventListener('click', avatarSelect2);
kidG.addEventListener('click', avatarSelect3);
surpG.addEventListener('click', avatarSelect4);

function avatarSelect (){
  console.log(avatar[0])
}
function avatarSelect1 (){
  console.log(avatar[1])
}
function avatarSelect2 (){
  console.log(avatar[2])
}
function avatarSelect3 (){
  console.log(avatar[3])
}
function avatarSelect4 (){
  console.log(avatar[4])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than attaching an event to each image object, it would be better to attach an event to the container surrounding it.

You can avoid overlapping codes and respond flexibly even if image objects increase.

for example

```
const imageContainer = document.getElementById("image-container");
imageContainer.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id); // you can get img tag's id
}
```

Comment: I have followed the above code and got this error.  Uncaught TypeError: imageContainer is null

Comment: I got it working had to change the code. document.querySelector("#avatar-container").addEventListener("click", e =>{
  console.log(e.target.id)
})

Comment: I'm sorry In your code, "image-container" was class, I though it was Id, thats why it's null. you correct it well!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how Event Bubbling and delegation work in javascript to get a better understanding but you want to add the event to the parent container not to each element. So by adding new elements to your array they will be clickable.

```js
const avatars = [
  'brownGorillaAvatar',
  'mainGorillaAvatar',
  'greenGorillaAvatar',
  'kidGorillaAvatar',
  'surpriseGorillaAvatar' 
]

const avatarContainer = document.querySelector('#avatarContainer');

avatars.forEach((avatar) => {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = avatar;
  avatarContainer.appendChild(span);
})

avatarContainer.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  console.log(evt.target);
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <section id="avatarContainer">
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```